# Какой частью речи является слово «русский»?

Tags: терминология, части-речи

Слово "русский" отвечает на вопрос ***какой?*** и при этом является существительным.
Я слышал, что есть специальное определение для таких слов. Не могли бы вы его подсказать?

Comment: Что такое "является существенным"?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На этот вопрос — в том виде как он поставлен — невозможно дать однозначного ответа.
Тут проблема в том, что и вопрос неоднозначно читается, и в том, что слово само по себе очень необычное — и по своей истории (не вполне, кстати прозрачной), и по функциям в языке.

Как можно трактовать вопрос.

Во-первых, слово русский отвечает на вопрос "какой?" только в одном из значений. Во втором, едва ли не главном, оно отвечает на вопрос "кто?". Такие слова называются ***многозначными***.

Во-вторых, возможно что вопрос действительно предполагал субстантивацию (см. slava1947). Действительно, слова, исходно не являющиеся существительными (обычно это прилагательные), но перешедшие в разряд таковых, называются ***субстантиватами***. Однако в отношении слова "русский" необходимо сделать оговорку. У филологов нет единого мнения о том, что от чего образовалось. Слово это неясной этимологии — и очень может быть, что слово изначально обозначало именно лицо, человека (причем совсем непонятно, по какому признаку). В этом случае говорить о субстантивации не совсем корректно.

Наконец, есть еще группа слов (в первую очередь — русские фамилии и топонимы), "маскирующихся" под другую часть речи. У них нет специального названия, но они могут доставлять много проблем при изучении — по разным причинам, например, из-за особенностей грамматики (образования некоторых падежных форм, одушевленность, трактовка этимологии).

Последняя проблема весьма дискуссионна — и вряд ли вопрос было об этом, поэтому я не стал здесь подробно излагать. А вот что касается первых двух трактовок — выбирайте. Или уточняйте вопрос.

Comment: И ещё может отвечать на вопрос "что?": *Что это за язык? Это русский.* В словаре это существительное с пометкой *разг*.

Comment: oleedd «Что это за женщина у вас в машине? ― спросил патрульный. ― Да это моя жена, ― печально ответил водитель.» ========= Слова ЖЕНА, ЖЕНЩИНА отвечают на вопрос «что?»